# Won't encrypt the character that is set?

Tags: java

I have code which looks right, I do not see what is wrong with it but the program output is not correct (specificity after the code):

Two Classes : `Test.java` and `Key.java`

Test.java:

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Key k1,k2;
    k1 = new Key(5);
    k2 = new Key(15);

    System.out.println(k1.encode('a')); // expected output 'f'
    System.out.println(k2.encode('a')); // expected output 'p'
    System.out.println(k1.encode('7')); // expected output '2'
}
```

Key.java:

```
class Key{
  private int value;

  Key(int value) {}

  public char encode(char c){
    if (isValidKey(value) != true) {
      return '.';             
    } else {
      int code = (int) c;
      code = code + value;
      c = (char) code;
      return c;
    }
}
```

When I run the test for inputs `a, a and 2` it simply returns  ... `a a and 2` (instead of the expected `f p and 2`).

Answer (score 1):

Value is always 0. Fix your constructor. This

```
Key(int value) {
}
```

should probably be this

```
Key(int value) {
  // Store the value in private this.value.
  this.value = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor actually needs to save the given value:

```
Key(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

You're now adding zero to each of your characters which means you'll indeed get `'a'` as output for `'a'` as input.

Answer (score 0):

In constructor of Key class, you probably need to set the value for variable `value`. so that the value of variable `value` can be changed. Have a try this and go ahead to see if there is any further issue.

From

```
Key(int value) {

}
```

To

```
Key(int value) {

    this.value = value;
}
```

In addition, it is not an issue, you can simply the following code

from

```
 if (isValidKey(value) != true) {
```

to

```
  if (!isValidKey(value)) {
```